# Django FilteredSelectMultiple: 'TypeError while rendering: unpack non-sequence'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to replace the default ManyToManyField widget in the Admin to use a FilteredSelectMultiple, and I'm having some issues.  My error is `Caught TypeError while rendering: unpack non-sequence`

Here is my model

```
class Car(models.Model):
    parts = models.ManyToManyField('Part')

class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

And this is my ModelAdmin

```
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = myforms.CustomCarForm
```

And this is CustomCarForm

```
 class CustomCarForm(forms.ModelForm):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(CustomCarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         parts = tuple(Part.objects.all())
         self.fields['parts'].widget = admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(
             'Parts', False, choices=parts
         )
```

I receive this error when I try to view the Admin form

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:        http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/foo/car/1/
Django Version:     1.2.5
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    Caught TypeError while rendering: unpack non-sequence
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.4.egg/django/forms/widgets.py in render_options, line 464
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.4.3
```

This error occurs if I use any of these to set `parts`

```
parts = Part.objects.all()
parts = list(Part.objects.all())
parts = tuple(Part.objects.all())
```

If I do this

```
parts = Part.objects.value_list('name')
```

I get `Caught ValueError while rendering: need more than 1 value to unpack`

**Edit**: If I take out `choices=parts` it renders fine, but the selection boxes are blank, and I need to have something in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
```

Apparently, choices is a list of tuples, first value being `option_value` and the second is `option_label`.

I'm not sure what the first needs to be, but I'm guessing pk.

Try:

```
parts = [(x.pk, x.name) for x in Part.objects.all()]
```